# Show the same text at the same position on every worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 worksheets in a workbook.

In every worksheet in this workbook I want to enter customer, project name and project manager in a certain position. These values are the same in att sheets.

Ideally I want the user to enter these details into one "admin sheet" and then have that information show in all sheets with no regards to their column widths.

What is a good way of doing this?

I have considered entering a text box into each of the 10 worksheets. But that has at least two drawbacks

- Users might accidentally select and move the text boxes and become confused and annoyed
- I have to have some kind of VBA worksheet change events that update the checkboxes when users change the project manager, client or project name in the admin sheet. This feels unnecessarily complex.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what do you mean by `no regards to their column widths`? that the width/position of the common data should be enforced to be in the same place on all sheets? or that it can have different widths/positions on each sheet?

Comment: I just noticed OP's comment under an answer: `I want the text to be displayed in the same position on all sheets.`

Comment: This question isn't clear at all - you need to provide an example of what you want the data to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a command button on the admin sheet and run this code from it?

```
Sub SO()

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not ws.Name = "admin sheet" Then _
        ws.Range("A1:B10").Value = Sheets("admin sheet").Range("A1:B10").Value

    ws.Columns("A:B").AutoFit

Next ws

End Sub
```

If you really wanted to you could assign this to a `Worksheet_Change()` event in the "admin sheet" module, but I would would recommend a button that the user at least has some control over.

Comment: I could. My mail question is about how to display values from one sheet on multiple sheets without any regard to the target sheets' column widths. In that case I can't use "ws.Range("A1:B10").Value = ". I can use a text box as I wrote about. But I think maybe there is a better solution for displaying data on multiple sheets without regard to the column width.

Comment: Have you tried the code? It just gets the values - it has nothing to do with column widths?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. And thank you for trying to help! What I mean is that if column A is narrow then the texts in column A and B will be close to each other. If column A is wide then they will be far from each other. I want the text to be displayed in the same position on all sheets.

Comment: please use `End If` instead of line continuation character for multi-line if statements to improve maintainability

Comment: Autofit does not help. The columns contain more information on other rows. Some columns have a lot of text while other columns have less text. I need a method for showing information on a sheet that is not column dependent. I know that textbox is one such method. But I think there are other better methods that I don't know about. Maybe it is possible to take a live picture of four cells and have it show anywhere? Or something like that

Comment: It only appears as a multi-line statement for the purpose of display on this site, It is intended to be run as a single line conditional command.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Insert` > `Shapes` > e.g. `Text Box` or `Rounded Rectangle`, then click on the *Formula bar* while the new shape is selected and type a reference to a cell on your admin sheet, e.g.
 `='admin sheet'!A1` and format the shape as appropriate.

Make sure to `Format Shape...` > `Properties` > `Don't move or size with cells`.

[image: text box with formula screenshot]

When you are done with designing a sheet, select all to-be-editable cells and in right-click menu `Format cells...` on `Protection` tab untick `Lock cells` to enable editing of these cells even after you [protect the sheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4) in the next step:

Use `Review` > `Protect Sheet` - you don't have to use any password and you can enable all actions that the users are supposed to do, just do NOT check `Edit Objects` tickbox if you want to prevent users from moving the shapes.